# Automatic BLE disconnect-connect - Windows10, Android

Tags: android, windows, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I try to reconnect, **immediate and automatic [disconnect-connect-disconnect-...]** happens before they truly connect and read/write/subscribe.

---

- **PC:** Windows10(1903), using CSR 4.0 dongle + UWP app for BLE pairing/connection
- **Mobile:** LG V40, Galaxy Note5, LG X Power, Galaxy S9+, Galaxy S10

> **V40** *ALMOST ALWAYS*: automatic quick discon-con happens 10 times or more
>
> **S10** *ALMOST ALWAYS*: similar to V40. *First connection (step 3 below) doesn't work. Takes forever to find the services that I get timeout disconnect.
>
> **Note5** *HALF OF THE TIME*: similar to V40
>
> The above 3 devices sometimes never truly connects (I waited 70 times and just disconnected by myself)
>
> **X Power** *SOMETIMES*: usually less than 10 times
>
> **S9+** *RARELY*: similar to X Power

---

Here are the [etl files](https://github.com/Jess103/Debug-BthTracing) I traced bluetooth logs.

- Please refer to V40 and Note5 logs (IGNORE X Power; I traced it for different issue)

**I want to know if mobile does it or PC does it or both and HOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE (if I can...)**

Any help is appreciated!!

---

More Info. Just in Case:

1. Client(PC) searches for the Server(Mobile)
2. Pair
3. Connect (reading/writing/subscribing notification works PERFECTLY)
4. Disconnect (Unsubscription done before disposing)
5. Connect (automatic and quick [discon-con-discon-con-discon-...] happens before they truly connect that PC can write/subscribe so on)

Comment: Because of random MAC.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! I thought the MAC doesn't change after the pairing and that is why I can reconnect using the same `bluetoothLeDevice.Id` with creating new session and adding `ConnectionStatusChangedHandler`. Sorry I'm new to bluetooth that I'm not really sure what's happening.. Can you please explain in more detail? :)

Comment: Its long story but in few words: I can not be 100% sure about your device but all Android devices I used has random public MAC. Sometimes such random MAC can be resolved to private MAC. But Windows does not do it and Android\s public MAC is real random (can not be resolved). So re-pair with your device or simple do not pair (because actualy pairing with BLE gives nothing on Windows, Windows even can not generate correct encryption key).

Comment: Thank you for explaining me. Unfortunately, I have to pair before connecting cuz my PC throws null for `await bluetoothLeDevice.FromIdAsync` if I don't. Also, it doesn't quiet make sense that I can reconnect to the device with the previous MAC if the MAC keep changing. [The last line of the checked answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200474/mac-randomization-for-bluetooth) also states that "bonded device is capable of resolving the random MAC to permanant (public) MAC." And now I'm lost again... :(

Comment: Use FromAddressAsync (or something like that) instead. Re-discover device before connect. As I wrote it does not work on Windows. Wincods can not resolve MAC. Actualy it event does not execute pairing (secure pairing) with device. It uses Just-works in your case that does not resolve MAC. Only secure pairing can (OK, correct word is "should") resolve MAC on Windows. But even it "should" it does not work. There are tons of bugs in MS BLE implementation. Why I can tell that? Because I am with Bluetooth past 18 years (https://www.btframework.com)

Comment: Thank you again for your detailed explanation! I thought the randomly generated MAC for PC doesn't matter in my case since PC is the one who's looking for the device. I tried `await BluetoothLEDevice.FromAddressAsync` before, but this requires pairing as well. Also, user cannot interact during the  reconnection (cuz it' done on background, when screen is locked) that I cannot scan and "choose" the device; I need to "remember" id/address that won't change... I'll try CustomPairing for secure pairing! (Hope this helps) Thank you so much again for your comment! :)

Comment: FromAddressAsync  does nto require pairing. You did something wrong. try GattClient from Bluetooth Framework to check your device requirements. In BluetoothManager you can check address type.

Comment: Oh, I also forgot to say one impotant thing: Android phone appears as Mixed device for Windows (not as pure BLE). So during pairing Windows may switches to Classic Bluetooth MAC and save it instead of BLE MAC. This is one more reason why you can not reconnect. Better to test with pure BLE device. Or at least with Raspberry Pi that appears as pure BLE device when runs bleno.

Comment: I' so sorry to bother you, but I want to make it clear. [**Current State: I CAN RECONNECT w/ paired devices using the previous id**, which looks like xx:xx:xx:xx:xx-xx:xx:xx:xx:xx. It seemed like the first half is PC address and the latter one is the device's address. (**Reconnection w/ S9+ or X Power is done perfectly 99% of the time, having no such ridiculous connection state changes**. Others have several state changes before the 'real' connection, and sometimes the state chages forever that I just choose to disconnect by my own)]

Comment: [**Reason I Need to Pair: USER CANNOT INTERACT DURING RECONNECTION** (i.e. PC needs to get bleObject, the device, and initiate connection by its own; to do this, PC needs to know the permanent id/address of the device)] [**What I Should Try: 1)Secure Pairing 2)FromAddressAsync 3)Check if PC getting BT, not BLE, address of the device**] Is this correct? Am I still missing something? Again, I'm really sorry to bother you and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Well. It is really long explanation for that. Can you ping me by skype (mike.petrichenko) so we can discuss it there. You can add our skype conversation later as an answer here.

Comment: What are etl files? The best way to debug these kind of issues is to look at sniffer logs.

Comment: @Mike_Petrichenko Sorry it was a late night here that I went to bed... I'll check if my company has blocked skype or not (hope not) when I get there. If it is blocked, can we use hangouts instead? Since it's gonna take about an hour and a half for me to get there and you might be tired by then, plz lemme know what time do you feel better in your time (ex. 1pm tmr in California time) Is this ok w/ you?

Comment: @Emil those are the log traced on the PC side, following [this](https://github.com/microsoft/busiotools/tree/master/bluetooth/tracing)

Comment: @Mike I'm adding this comment to make sure that you get notification

Comment: Unfortunately no, i did not get any notifications. I am also available by WtasApp and Viber (use phone number from our site https://www.btframework.com/contacts.htm). Its 1:22 here (night) but I'll be available in next 1 or 2 hours

Comment: Or you can simple e-mail me (mike@btframework.com) and I'll try to describe all my real experience with BLE on Windows.

Comment: So sad that @ doesn't work at all and neither my company... It's blocking almost everywhere dah! :( I'll send you and e-mail. Take your time; you don't have to reply me back asap or so... Take a rest first! I feel so bad to keep you awake... Again, sorry and thank you so much

Comment: Logs show the radio hardware used by the host side by you is hitting a racing condition that will result in MIC errors due to collision over the air. You should first make sure the drivers for the radio are the most updated (multiple radios had this issue in the past) and then if that doesn’t work try to switch to a different radio hardware/dongle to try again.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT thank you for the comment! So what I need to do is: 1) Check the BT radio driver if it is most updated 2)Change the dongle (if 1 doesn't work), right? I hope I can fix this issue via the first method cuz this ridiculous auto con-discon happens in Surfacebook and Probook as well...

Comment: Yes, if the drivers are the most updated and still doesn't work, you can try to use a different radio hardware/dongle to see will the same issue occur.